Kanshi crashes Qtile Wayland
I am currently trying to use kenshi to automatically use my external display’s when connecting to my dock. But doing so either results in Qtile crashing or not recognizing my displays and staying with only eDP-1 on.
Here is my config:
profile docked {
    output eDP-1 disable
    output DP-7 enable position 0,0 mode 1920x1080@60Hz
    output DP-5 enable position 1920,0 mode 1920x1080@60Hz
    output DP-6 enable position 3840,0 mode 1920x1080@60Hz
}

profile laptop {
    output eDP-1 enable position 0,0 scale 1.5
}

I've tried looking here:
https://man.archlinux.org/man/kanshi.1.en
https://man.archlinux.org/man/kanshi.5.en
https://sr.ht/~emersion/kanshi/
